# Adding a custom cell at the end of tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a situation where I need to display more than one sections in a grouped table. Each section has three content rows and I need a `"View More"` row. The content row will open a detail view, where as "view more" will open a tableview with status messages. Need some help with

1. The prototype cell is set to have the image and the labels. So I am not sure how to add the "View More" Row in the end.
2. Am I right in using dynamic prototypes ( I have it working pretty much) or is static cells the right choice?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The prototype cell is set to have the image and the labels. So I am not sure how to add the "View More" Row in the end.

You are not limited to a single prototype cell per table. Add a custom cell for the "View More" cell, then add some code to your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to pick the "main" prototype for the top cells, and the "view more" prototype for the last cell.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    if (indexPath.row != [self numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"mainPrototype"];
        ...
    } else {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"viewMorePrototype"];
        ...
    }
    return cell;
}
```

> Am I right in using dynamic prototypes ( I have it working pretty much) or is static cells the right choice?

Yes, this is the right choice.

Comment: Thanks. I think i get the idea. will try it out. I need to figure out how to add more than one prototype cells as I am using story board. May be simply drag and drop another cell and give an identifier?

Comment: @aVC Yes, that's correct - add another cell, and give it a different reuse identifier.

Comment: is it possible for you (given your high standing) to recommend a feature to SO? to save Qns that are (or going to be in future) useful into "Favorites" (or something like that), so that we can come back and see all the saved ones instead of searching for it again?

Comment: @aVC, up in the left hand side of the screen where people can upvote your question, there is a star.  Click on the star and it will save it as your favorite.  Then in your user page you can see all your favorites.  dasblinkenlight, I hope I didn't step on your toes answering this.

Comment: @Douglas Thank you so much. I was looking for this for sooo long.

Answer (score 1):

Create an array to contain all the status messages. Group them according to the section when you initialise the screen. You could give the same index to the groups as the section as well. In the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, when a particular section is clicked, pass the particular section of the status messages to the next view controller.

Hope you get my idea and this helps you..

Adding the custom cell to the end of each section can be done as @dasklinkenlight said...